# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement 1

Tags: vb.net

I am receiving the following when trying to add data into a database.

**Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.**

Can anyone help plz? Thanks

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Order History] ([Order ID], [Item ID], [Items Sold], [Cases on hold], [Cases suggested to order], [Cases Ordered]) VALUES (@id, @iId, @iSold, @cHold, @csOrder, @cOrdered)"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtOrderID.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iId", txtItemID.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iSold", txtItemsSold.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cHold", txtCasesonhold.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@csOrder", txtCasessuggestedtoorder.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cOrdered", txtCasesOrdered.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: `Order History` should probably be escaped also: `[Order History]`...and you should start accepting answers

Comment: I have tried and tested but it still doesnt seem to be working

Comment: whats the complete error, not just the additional info?  edit your post to reflect the change please

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll.

Comment: Some of those fields look like numbers, not "Text".

Comment: what database?  OleDB suggests access which does not support named params

Comment: a) are you sure you have a table named `Order History` b) did you apply Lars' comment - all those columns look like numbers, but you are adding Text.  I think that throws a data mismatch error though.

Comment: Yes.... What will I have to change if they are number fields?

Comment: change the **text** you are passing in `.AddWithValue` to the appropriate **numeric** type.

Comment: Could you give me example plz

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a `System.Data.OleDbCommand` object try:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Order History] ([Order ID], [Item ID], [Items Sold], [Cases on hold], [Cases suggested to order], [Cases Ordered]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtOrderID.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iId", txtItemID.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iSold", txtItemsSold.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cHold", txtCasesonhold.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@csOrder", txtCasessuggestedtoorder.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cOrdered", txtCasesOrdered.Text)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement. The question mark (?) placeholder must be used. See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx.

Comment: it is now coming up with the error data type mismatch in criteria expression